# how to automate manage transactions in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

When use java Hibernate & Spring framework, there is a transaction manager which we can configure some transaction rules, then we don't need write "commit, flush, rollback" stuff each time.

Comment: SQL Alchemy comes with decorators and context managers to automate transaction management: a transaction (optionally a nested one) is created at the start, and then it's rolled back if you exit with an exception or committed if you exit normally. Is that what you're looking for, or something different?

Comment: Have a look at how Pyramid handles transactions. It involves the Zope extension and tools and `pyramid_tm`, if my memory serves me right.

Comment: @abarnert ah, yes, that's i'm looking for, thx!!!

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for your comment, i'll take a look of that when i get chance.

Comment: Cool. If you think your question would be useful to other people, consider cleaning up your question to be a bit more specific, then writing and accepting your own answer. If not, you can just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python SQL Alchemy, we can use decorators and context managers to manage transactions(official sample from [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_basics.html)):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()


def run_my_program():
    with session_scope() as session:
        ThingOne().go(session)
        ThingTwo().go(session)
```

an [transactions library](http://transaction.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sqlalchemy.html) is also a good choice to do that.